# Validate date strings in Ruby with multiple accepted formats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, date

I have some strings that might or might not be dates like:

```
"Hello World", "Sept 12, 2013", "Hello World Sept 12"
```

In this case, I'd like only the second one to be considered a proper date.

So far, I have been using `Date.parse` and the Chronic gem but they very lenient and convert strings like `"a a"` or `"12-UNKN/34/OWN1"` into acceptable dates.

For example:

```
Date.parse '12-UNKN/34/OWN1'
```

would return:

```
 Tue, 12 Nov 2013
```

So, I am trying to restrict the accepted formats to a set of formats I can control:

```
09/12/2013
9/12/2013
9/12/13
09-12-2013
9-12-2013
9-12-13
```

and some formats with text inside like:

```
Sept 9, 2013 - with or without the coma, accepting Sep, Sept or September and with or without a dot after the month name, covering things like:
Sept. 9, 2013
Sept 09, 2013
Sept. 09, 2013
September 9, 2013
September 09, 2013
```

Any suggestion on a good way to do this in Ruby, either pure Ruby or with Rails?

Comment: Humor me...  Why so many accepted formats?  Wouldn't it be easier to allow only one format?

Comment: For example when I don't control the given text, e.g the text comes from a title written by a user like "Going there on Nov. 2, 2013" or "Who will be there on 03/12/2014?".

Comment: Just use `validates_format_of` with a regex that handles all the date types that you want before passing them to Chronic.

Comment: @GrahamConzett answer is correct - just absent of the elaboration you need to do regarding acceptable date formats.  If you want your porridge to be *just right* then only you can know what it will be

Comment: Agree with both of the previous two comments... As I think through this, given your examples, what if some enters September 2nd as dd-mm-yyyy...  How will you know if they mean September 2nd or February 9th?

Comment: I am not aware than you can use the regular date formatting helpers like %m, %B, etc... in validates_format_of. Will check this out.
"September 2nd" without a year would fail the validation. I wouldn't support both mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy but only mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at this and elaborate on my comment. Separating the date from the other string allows you to validate the date in multiple formats before handing it off to Chronic:

`validates_format_of :date, with: /\d{2,4}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,4}/, on: :create`

That should handle most of the date formats you described.

However, a big issue is you won't know if someone is submitting a date in the US format or non-US format.

The bigger issue is know what part of the title string is in fact a date, and that would either be a more complicated regular expression, or make it easy on yourself and make it a separate field. You're getting somewhat close to trying to parse natural language which isn't cut and dry by any means.

Comment: I played with this a bit and it will cover nicely the dates with only digits. The harder cases are the months that need to cover the different like "Sept. 09, 2012" or "Sep 09, 2012". That's why I was looking into a solution where I could leverage the existing ruby Date utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
validate :validate_some_date

private

def validate_some_date
  errors.add("Created at date", "is invalid.") unless [
      date_case_one,
      date_case_two,
      date_case_three
    ].all?
end

def date_case_one
  # some regex
end

def date_case_two
  # some regex
end

def date_case_three
  # some regex
end
```